# Place text in the center of a div while ignoring other elements inside of it

Tags: html, css

There is a big div which contains two buttons which are at the end.

```
<big-div>            <small-div>my text</small-div>      <button1><button2></big-div>
```

I want the text inside `small-div` to be centered with respect to the `big-div` ignoring the buttons. Now it not in center but a little closer to the left side because of the buttons.

CSS files:

```
.big-div {
    display: flex;
}

.button1 {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: .25em;
}
.button2 {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: .25em;
}

.small-div {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0d1e2c;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Any suggestions about how to "ignore" the buttons when positioning the text?

```css
.big-div {
display: flex;
background-color: red;
width:100%;
height: 100px;
}

.small-div {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0d1e2c;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.buttons {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-div">
 <div class="small-div">my text</div>
 <button class="buttons">button1</button>
 <button class="buttons">button2</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using *valid* HTML so we can see what you are trying to do, and be able to give you answers that will solve the real problem you have!

Comment: @FluffyKitten, done

Comment: Are you using Sass and Less and CSS all in the same project?

Comment: @HereticMonkey only sass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` to the `.small-div` and `justify-content: flex-end;` to the `.big-div`:

```css
.big-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; 
}

.button1 {
  margin-left: .25em;
}

.button2 {
  margin-left: .25em;
}

.small-div {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0d1e2c;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="big-div">
  <div class="small-div">
    small div is here
  </div>
  <button class="button1">button1</button>
  <button class="button2">button2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. Please explain how this code works to fix the problem, so that it is helpful to other users who have the same question also :)

Answer (score 0):

css rule 'position: absolute;' will make div position not relative to other elements on page. So you can place it freely.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an absolute value to where you want it to go

i.e.

```
.small-div {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0d1e2c;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```